# Error Highcharts generated in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, highcharts

good night have a problem with Highcharts graphs
as you can see I have 3 graphs on the same page
it turns out that the pimera takes me just a menu to download and the other of a 2 or 3 not may be going
in the console.log I generated this error

Uncaught Error: Highcharts error #16: www.highcharts.com/errors/16

controller and view
http://codepad.org/Rl2NhDGm

chart.js
http://codepad.org/Zm2hOlAs

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is to do with your  tags, somehow you have included highcharts more than once.

Highcharts already defined in the page

This error happens the second time Highcharts or Highstock is loaded in the same page, so the Highcharts namespace is already defined. Keep in mind that the Highcharts.Chart constructor and all features of Highcharts are included in Highstock, so if you are running Chart and StockChart in combination, you only need to load the highstock.js file.